# Canon MG2550 printer: "check your printer configuration"

Tags: drivers, printing, libreoffice, canon

I’m trying to print from Libre Office Writer (Version: 6.4.3.2) on Focal. This is the first time I have connected the printer since installing Ubuntu as a dual boot.

As soon as the printer was plugged in it was recognised as MG2550 series. But when I went to print I get an error message saying,

> **Print Cancelled**
> Could not start printer. Check your printer configuration.

I have been through the tutorial [Printer Canon MG2550 Driver for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal How to Download & Install](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/12/06/printer-canon-mg2550-driver-for-ubuntu-20-04-focal-how-to-download-install/3/), which all seems to have gone fine. I now have 2 printers showing ‘mg2550 - series’ and ‘mg2550’, neither of which will print.

The printer’s definitely turned on, and both the PC and the printer have been turned off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download a printer driver for my Canon MG2500 printer from the following webiste:

https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2550.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux (64-bit)

If the `install.sh` scripts don't work, use `dpkg -i` for your respective architecture.